# Is it ok to use ConfigurationBuilder to bind custom json files to POCO classes?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, configuration

I want to bind json file section to POCO class, I have started using ConfigurationBuilder for convenience as it already encapsulates file reading, so comparing to solution with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring) usage I do not have to deal with jsonstring fetching from bigger file, also I can use AddEnvironmentVariables during ConfigurationBuilder object creation so I can even use secrets set as env vars. Example usage from my code:

```
var infrastructureConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
     .AddJsonFile("infrastructureSettings.json", false, true)
     .AddEnvironmentVariables()
     .Build();

_serviceBusConfiguration = new ServiceBusConfiguration();
infrastructureConfig.GetSection("ServiceBus").Bind(_serviceBusConfiguration);
```

Is this approach valid or ConfigurationBuilder should rather be used only for app config files? Is there any better approach?